# Xfinity Modem Bridge Mode -> Switch -> Router, is this a security concern?

Tags: networking, router, nat

I have an xfinity router that I want to set it under bridge mode. The router connects to a switch that a) does port mirroring to an IDS NIC (under promiscuous mode) and b) connects via another port to my router that will be running under router mode (enabling NAT, DHCP and Firewall).

All my network devices connect to the router. Even for the IDS I use my wifi to connect to it.

My main concerns are:

- the "exposed" Switch. It does have a web interface that belongs to my subnet (router subnet not xfinity).
- by putting xfinity router under bridge mode, do I lose NAT on it? In other words, will the traffic that the IDS will be observing being pre-NAT?

Comment: Will the IDS be pre-nat? ~yes. by putting xfinity router under bridge mode, do I lose NAT on it? ~yes, it becomes more like a media converter for Docsis<---->Ethernet. You should add the switch make and model to the question, just to make sure we are on the same page. This is the only thing in your question that is currently unanswerable. Please add the additional info to the **question** and not the **comments**.